# Verizon LG Cosmos Mobile Broadband?

Tags: 13.10, mobile-broadband, lg, cdma

I plugged in my cell phone (Verizon LG Cosmos) with Ubuntu 13.10 running and a notification came up about Mobile Broadband. I enabled it and it connected to Verizon CDMA. Can someone explain what is going on and what is happening?

Comment: "I plugged in my cell phone" - was this with a USB lead to your PC which had Ubuntu running?
"a notification came up about Mobile Broadband" Did the notification come up on the mobile or the PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means that you're connected to their 3G/4G network on your computer and you should be able to access the internet through your phone.

Be careful though! This takes up a load of data!